# How can i remove the block which is present in some other module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, customer-account

[image]

I want to remove "my product reviews" which is in magento_review module. The whole sider is in magento_customer. I am override magento_customer's customer_account.xml layout in my custom module. How can i remove it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add below code in particular layout handler in your module or theme:

```
<referenceBlock name="block-name-you-want-to-remove" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed "Be the first to review this product" link and "Reviews" Tab (Review Form) from my product detail page using below code in my theme.
Path of layout xml file in my theme: 
app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
```

First line will remove "Be the first to review this product" link and second line will remove "Reviews" Tab.
Hope this will help you.